# How to display a paragraph with images and rich text in android text view. Content can be stored in xml

Tags: android, textview, rtf

I have some contents which contains images and rich text format, and links which should work in android. How can i display them in android text view. and where i should store the content.  What is the best practice ? use HTML content or break it in separate text and image views ?

For example i want to make a text view like the image below.

[image: sample view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);

IconFontSpan iconFontSpan = new IconFontSpan(textView.getContext());
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\u26F7");    // skier
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        spannableString.setSpan(iconFontSpan, 
        matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
    }


private static class IconFontSpan 
    extends MetricAffectingSpan {
private static Typeface typeface = null;
public IconFontSpan(Context context) {
  if (typeface == null) {
    typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        context.getAssets(), "icomoon.ttf");
  }
}
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint textPaint) {
   textPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
}
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint) {
  textPaint.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

[image]

Here is the link:

> http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML and display it in the android webview, instead of textview.

Answer (score -1):

You should store your HTML and all contents to the assets folder.
Then load the html in the WebView. 
in your layout file write this code.

`<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>`

and from your Activity you can set the html like this.

`WebView webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.movieLoadingLoader);
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html_folder/index.html");`

Or,

If you want to load the HTML in your TextView , write this code .

`Textview tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
 tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>Hello World</h4>"));`